# Is Express Entry Pool Submission visible to IRCC Officer Processing Visitor Visa?

Tags: visas, canada, standard-visitor-visas

So I want to apply for Express Entry in future, I currently have visitor visa in processing. Would my entry to Express Entry pool potentially jeopardize, my current application as the visa officer might wrongly assume that i plan to immigrate on visitor visa (which I am not), due to my potential entry to the pool? I have seen plenty of rejection to candidates with good travel history, so I dont want to jeopardize with even slightest of the wrong assumption.

Would this addition of my application to pool be visible to the officer or is it only visible after ITA?

Comment: Have you applied for the pool yet?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella no I didnt. I wanted to understand the situation first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter.
Immigration intent is not disqualifying for Canadian visitor visa. [Dual intent](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/visitors/dual-intent-applicants.html) is in fact explicitly allowed.

The law requires you to convince the officer that you will leave Canada at the end of authorized stay. Whether you have registered for Express Entry or even submitted an application for permanent residence is in most cases irrelevant to that determination. Unless your profile is exceptional, the officer assumes a visa-required national probably wants to move to Canada anyway.

Comment: Legally a Dual intent is explicitly allowed. But dont you think that having submitted an application to the pool raises more skepticism in the eyes of the officer, when I have seen people with strong travel history and a valid B1/B2 visa have been denied a visa on the basis of "officer isnt convinced". If such strong justification such is travel history and valid US visa is not convincing enough for some individuals then isnt adding one's name in the pool and open invitation for the officer to reject the visitor visa? Besides my original question is.. (continued)

Comment: (continiued) "Would this addition of my application to pool be visible to the officer or is it only visible after ITA? "

Comment: @user0193 if they want they can look it up. But it is hardly relevant in most cases. They assume you want to immigrate to Canada. A profile can be seen as an intent to stay in Canada but also an intent to seek permanent residence legally. It may seem paradoxical but often people who can easily immigrate to Canada are less likely to be found that they will stay beyond the authorized period since that would jeopardize their legal path to PR.

Comment: @user0193 other parts of your application is far more important. Your EE profile can either show you want to go to Canada no matter what and you don't have a good stable well paying job in your home country or you are already a skilled well paid professional who won't risk illegal stay in another country. Your profile matters, your EE intention doesn't.

Comment: "if they want they can look it up" , this sums up my question. I have accepted this as valid answer.

Comment: revisiting your comments "It may seem paradoxical but often people who can easily immigrate to Canada are less likely to be found that they will stay beyond the authorized period since that would jeopardize their legal path to PR" are you suggesting that applying for EE might improve my chance of getting temporary PR as having a good profile for EE one is less likely to abuse the temporary visitor visa?